# How to build in Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I would like to build the attached in bootstrap with it being responsive dependent on screen size.

On tablet devices and smaller I would like the image to be edge to edge of the screen with the content section indented in the bottom of the image slightly.

Any help/guidance would be great!

Thanks[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Owm26.png)

Comment: Please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

In your header page add bootstrap example:

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/latest/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Ok here is your basic code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <style>
    .container {
      position: relative;
      font-family: Arial;
    }
    
    .text-block {
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 20px;
      left: 0px;
      background-color: black;
      color: white;
      padding-left: 20px;
      padding-right: 20px;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    
    <div class="container">
    <p style="width:170px;height:170px;margin-left:15px;">
      <img src="img_nature_wide.jpg" alt="Nature" class="img-responsive">
      </p>
      <div class="text-block">
        <h4>Nature</h4>
        <p>What a beautiful sunrise</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Please feel free to add bootstrap to style as needed

---

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  font-family: Arial;
}

.text-block {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  left: 0px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/latest/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <p style="width:170px;height:170px;margin-left:15px;">
    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_snow_wide.jpg" alt="Nature" class="img-responsive">
  </p>
  <div class="text-block">
    <h4>Nature</h4>
    <p>What a beautiful sunrise</p>
  </div>
</div>
```